# Float a DIV Left using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have two `div`s formatted as panels. One is the main panel whereas the other is something like a sidebar. I would like the sidebar to float to the left, but the latter is embedded inside the main `div`. I want it to display next to the main panel, rather than inside it.

I know I could float the sidebar left, the main panel right and add some more content after them and use `clear: both` to make the page resize and scroll properly; this sounds like a hack, however, and it requires specifying the size of both panels. If I could float just the sidebar to the left, then the main panel would size itself automatically to cover the rest of the page.

My HTML code at the moment looks something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar" class="panel">
    Sidebar
</div>

<div id="content" class="panel">
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
    <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

And the CSS of interest is:

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
```

In the screenshot below, one can easily see that the sidebar is floating to the left, but is somehow inside the main panel. In the HTML code, however, the sidebar is clearly outside the main panel. How can I fix that without having to use `float: right` on the main panel?

[image: Ugly Result]

Comment: use `float: left` on the main panel?

Comment: U need to clear floating divs

Comment: As I mention in my question, using `float: left/right` on the main panel would require specifying its size, since it won't cover the rest of the screen anymore. I know how to do it in an ugly way: `main panel` -> `float right`, `sidebar` -> `float left`, a hidden `hr` after those that uses `clear: both` and specifying the size for both panels manually. I am looking for an elegant solution that could work by specifying just the size of the sidebar.

Comment: you should read https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context . then add overflow:hidden to #content and you will understand why it works ;)

Comment: use `#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    
}`

Comment: In this specific case when you want the main content to take up the remaining width I would use `flexbox`, it makes your like easier. Read all about it [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can can make the *main panel* cover the rest of the *horizontal space*:

1. Specify `display: flex` on the wrapper element (`body` in the demo below)
2. Add `flex: 1` to the main panel so that if *grows* to fit the remaining space available.

See simplified demo below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  border: 1px solid;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 30%;
}

#content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar" class="panel">
  Sidebar
</div>

<div id="content" class="panel">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Sounds like what I need. Give me a moment to try it.

Comment: Know that flexbox is not supported in IE9. I would not use this solution.

Comment: Ehm... Internet Explorer 9 is fairly old nowadays, isn't it?

Comment: IE11 has PARTIAL support for flexbox, which means it might not work correctly in IE11. It does not work at all in IE9, which has 0.16% market share globally.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}

.clearfix:after,.clearfix:before {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div id="sidebar" class="panel">
    Sidebar
  </div>

  <div id="content" class="panel">
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
      <p>Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want use floats - you should use float for both blocks, because float "creates own flow", that's why you got overlaying.

But I'd rather recommend you using flexboxes as it was mentioned before, because it's quite powerful technology which is widely supported.
According to this site https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox using flexbox is supported by 96.63% devices all over the world.

Comment: Know that flexbox is not supported in IE9. I would use this solution.

Comment: @JoostS You can use `@support` query in css for usage newest features with backward compatibility. But in this case you should do a bit more work.

Comment: This solution is the "non-elegant" one I was talking about in my question (please, read carefully guys). Flexbox is what I was looking for.

Comment: @AngelosSfakianakis display: inline-block for both also is possible

Comment: If you use @support you also have to write the fallback. More code = higher cost = bad idea.

Comment: The cost of code is maintenance and testing, not kilobytes.

Answer (score 0):

@Angelos you could use the old table layout so the left part has a fixed width and the right part takes up all the rest available space..